# Looking for a word

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word that means "doing something only because someone else wants it." For example, i am getting a chocolate birthday cake only because everyone else likes chocolate even though I wanted vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing [altruistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism) behaviour.

If you are looking for a word to drop into that example sentence then I must admit that is quite difficult. I don't think it's a normal use of the the word altruistic when referring to yourself.

For instance you might describe a third person as altruistic or indeed selfless.

George [selflessly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/selflessly) cooked a fish dish for his friend even though he personally hated fishy food.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [**indulgent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indulgent), however this does not mean that you are acting against your own interests (though it does imply that your interests are not considered), only that you are obliging others.

> i am getting a chocolate birthday cake to **indulge** everyone else even though I wanted vanilla.

Although [**oblige**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblige) (To do a service or favour) might work better:

> i am getting a chocolate birthday cake to **oblige** everyone else even though I wanted vanilla.

Comment: Yes. My choice was "obligatory" too.

Answer (score 0):

For you to get "a chocolate birthday cake only because everyone else likes chocolate even though . . . [you] wanted vanilla" indicates deferential behavior.

The word *deference* carries with it the concept of [submission](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deference) to the will of another (or others). The reason for the deference might be the "superior" rank of the person to whom you are deferring, or as in the case of the chocolate cake the reason may be to submit to "the will of the people."